# Why this claim_interface in rusb (rust libusb binding) is failed?

Tags: rust, usb, libusb

I have tried to write bulk to an usb device to learn how to use libusb from rust.
To do above I have attempted to do that write some data with bulk mode when only pixel6 is connected.

The following is the code, you may feel it bit disgusting but for simply, Almost of all error handings are omitted.

An error is caused when claim_interface is called.

When `claim_interface` has called, the error caused that `NotFound`.
It seems like means there is no interface that assigned to the given interface number according to error reference of rusb.

https://docs.rs/rusb/latest/rusb/enum.Error.html#variant.NotFound

Why the error is happen?

Log:

```
[timestamp] [threadID] facility level [function call] <message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 0.005973] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_list]  
[ 0.005981] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_descriptor]  
[ 0.005983] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_open] open 7.8
[ 0.006006] [000015a8] libusb: debug [usbi_add_event_source] add fd 7 events 4
[ 0.006009] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_descriptor]  
[ 0.006011] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_get_config_descriptor] index 0
[ 0.006015] [000015a8] libusb: debug [parse_endpoint] skipping descriptor 0x30
[ 0.006016] [000015a8] libusb: debug [parse_endpoint] skipping descriptor 0x30
[ 0.006021] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_kernel_driver_active] interface 0
[ 0.006023] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_set_configuration] configuration 0
[ 0.007677] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_claim_interface] interface 0
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotFound', src/bulk.rs:37:68
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
[ 0.007738] [000015a8] libusb: debug [libusb_close]  
[ 0.007743] [000015a8] libusb: debug [usbi_remove_event_source] remove fd 7
```

Code:

```
use rusb::devices;
use rusb::Direction::{In, Out};
use rusb::TransferType::{Bulk, Control};
use rusb::{open_device_with_vid_pid, TransferType};
use std::time::Duration;
pub fn pixel6_bulk() {
    write_to_device(6353, 20199, Bulk);
}

fn write_to_device(vendor_id: u16, product_id: u16, ttype: TransferType) {
    let mut has_kernel_driver: bool = false;
    if let Some(mut device_handle) = open_device_with_vid_pid(vendor_id, product_id) {
        let dev = device_handle.device();
        let dd = dev.device_descriptor().unwrap();
        let num_config = dd.num_configurations();
        for p in 0..num_config {
            let cd = dev.config_descriptor(p).unwrap();
            let ifaces = cd.interfaces();
            for iface in ifaces {
                let inumber = iface.number();
                let ifds = iface.descriptors();
                for ifd in ifds {
                    let setting_number = ifd.setting_number();
                    for efd in ifd.endpoint_descriptors() {
                        if efd.direction() == Out && efd.transfer_type() == ttype {
                            let buf: &[u8] = "Hello".as_bytes();
                            let endpoint_address = efd.address();
                            if device_handle.kernel_driver_active(inumber).unwrap() {
                                has_kernel_driver =
                                    match device_handle.detach_kernel_driver(inumber) {
                                        Ok(_) => true,
                                        _ => false,
                                    };
                            }
                            //let endpoint_number = efd.number();
                            device_handle.set_active_configuration(p).unwrap();
                            device_handle.claim_interface(inumber).unwrap();
                            device_handle
                                .set_alternate_setting(inumber, setting_number)
                                .unwrap();
                            match device_handle.write_bulk(
                                endpoint_address,
                                buf,
                                Duration::new(2, 0),
                            ) {
                                Ok(n) => println!("{} bytes was written with bulk", n),
                                Err(_) => println!("Write_bulk was failed"),
                            }
                            if has_kernel_driver {
                                match device_handle.attach_kernel_driver(inumber) {
                                    Ok(_) => (),
                                    Err(_) => println!("Kernel driver attach failed"),
                                }
                            }
                            device_handle.release_interface(inumber).unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        panic!("There is no device");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: thanks for reply!!
I have edited the question to add the log.

Comment: Which is line 37? This is where instead of `unwrap()` you use [`expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) which can include contextual information. Generally you'll want to restrict use of those types of functions on results which are highly unlikely to fail, but as you've demonstrated here, that is not the case, so you probably want to handle this properly with a `match`.

Comment: If `device_handle.kernel_driver_active(inumber).unwrap()` returns `false` you reuse `has_kernel_driver` of the previous loop, is that on purpose?